# Allocated Stock Qty based on Order Qty in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a query below to allocated stock qty to match order qty based on order type. The problem is the stock qty is not updated.

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE
    (DealerCode NVARCHAR(50),
     PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderQty INT,
     OrderType NVARCHAR(50)
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblOrder
        ( DealerCode,
          PartCode,
          OrderQty,
          OrderType )
VALUES  ('D1','A',19,'Urgent'),
('D2','B',10,'Normal'),
('D3','C',11,'HotLine'),
('D1','D',20,'Normal'),
('D2','E',12,'Normal'),
('D1','D',40,'Normal');

DECLARE @tblStock TABLE
    (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     StockQty INT)
INSERT  INTO @tblStock
        ( PartCode,
          StockQty)
VALUES  ('A',20),
('B',15),
('C',9),
('D',30),
('E',0)

;WITH ordertemp AS (
select ord.dealercode, 
      ord.partcode, 
      ord.orderqty, 
      ord.ordertype,
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.dealercode) 'StockPriority',
      sto.stockqty 'InitialStock'
from @tblorder ord
left outer join @tblstock sto
on ord.partcode = sto.partcode )
SELECT
    Orders.dealercode,
    Orders.partcode,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Stock',
    Orders.orderqty,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty + Orders.OrderQty < Orders.InitialStock THEN Orders.OrderQty 
            WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Allocated',
    Orders.ordertype
FROM 
    ordertemp Orders
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT A.stockpriority, A.partcode, ISNULL(SUM(B.orderqty),0) 'PriorQty'
    from ordertemp A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertemp B
    on A.partcode = B.partcode
    and A.stockpriority > B.stockpriority 
    group by A.stockpriority, A.partcode ) Backlog
    ON Orders.stockpriority = Backlog.stockpriority
ORDER BY Orders.StockPriority
```

I got result:

```
dealercode  partcode    stock   orderqty    allocated   ordertype
D3  C   9   11  9   HotLine
D1  A   20  19  19  Urgent
D2  B   15  10  10  Normal
D1  D   30  20  20  Normal
D1  D   30  40  30  Normal
D2  E   0   12  0   Normal
```

Actually, the stock (30) of partcode 'D' must be remain 10 after allocated 20.
Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reason you get stock 30 is because your are using `RANK` for prioritization. `RANK` will allocate the same number to two order records if they have the same stock priority as defined by your condition `ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.dealercode`. If you check the output of `ordertemp` you will see

```
dealercode  partcode    orderqty    ordertype   StockPriority   InitialStock
D3  C   11  HotLine 1   9
D1  A   19  Urgent  2   20
D2  B   10  Normal  3   15
D1  D   20  Normal  4   30
D1  D   40  Normal  4   30
D2  E   12  Normal  6   0
```

Notice that the `StockPriority` of `partcode D` is `4` for both rows 4 and 5.

You can fix this by using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()` . You can also add `orderqty` in `ROW_NUMBER()` to specify if you want higher priority for smaller/larger orders if they have the same `ordertype, partcode` and `dealercode`.

**Query** with `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE
    (DealerCode NVARCHAR(50),
     PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderQty INT,
     OrderType NVARCHAR(50)
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblOrder
        ( DealerCode,
          PartCode,
          OrderQty,
          OrderType )
VALUES  ('D1','A',19,'Urgent'),
('D2','B',10,'Normal'),
('D3','C',11,'HotLine'),
('D1','D',20,'Normal'),
('D2','E',12,'Normal'),
('D1','D',40,'Normal');

DECLARE @tblStock TABLE
    (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     StockQty INT)
INSERT  INTO @tblStock
        ( PartCode,
          StockQty)
VALUES  ('A',20),
('B',15),
('C',9),
('D',30),
('E',0)

;WITH ordertemp AS (
select ord.dealercode, 
      ord.partcode, 
      ord.orderqty, 
      ord.ordertype,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.dealercode) 'StockPriority',
      sto.stockqty 'InitialStock'
from @tblorder ord
left outer join @tblstock sto
on ord.partcode = sto.partcode )

SELECT
    Orders.dealercode,
    Orders.partcode,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Stock',
    Orders.orderqty,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty + Orders.OrderQty < Orders.InitialStock THEN Orders.OrderQty 
            WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Allocated',
    Orders.ordertype
FROM 
    ordertemp Orders
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT A.stockpriority, A.partcode, ISNULL(SUM(B.orderqty),0) 'PriorQty'
    from ordertemp A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertemp B
    on A.partcode = B.partcode
    and A.stockpriority > B.stockpriority 
    group by A.stockpriority, A.partcode ) Backlog
    ON Orders.stockpriority = Backlog.stockpriority
ORDER BY Orders.StockPriority
```

Comment: Thanks @ughai, one more, any idea if I would like to divide qty of allocation equally for ordertype Normal. ex. Stock Qty=10, DealerCode order (D1=1,D2=2,D3=4,D4=6) then Allocated Qty should be (D1=1,D2=3,D3=3,D4=3)

Comment: you could count the total number of orders and total quantity which fall under each `ordertype` like normal for a part and then use it as a reference to distribute an equal percentage between all such orders

Comment: I could find total number/quantity of part under each ordertype, but how to distribute percentage equally?

Answer (score 0):

He's quite right above - when you first posted I had made the assumption you'd only have one entry per supplier per part / priority rather than duplicates :)

Note if you added orderquantity you would still face a problem if you had 2 entries with the same quantity in each.

Comment: heh no worries - got ya there in the end eh. Did you pick it up from here or the other site? :)

Comment: I got from this site. I prefer to allocated stock equally, could you kindly help me out?

Comment: @Sokea - I just saw your new question. will answer on top of that